# Avoiding incoming calls taking over the active app?

Tags: calls

Can we avoid incoming calls taking up the full size of the display while we're in the middle of stuff in other apps?

I appreciate that was a natural feature 10 years ago, but right now displays are large and I fail to see why it's not possible to just have a notification (or an overlay of some 30% of the size of the display, without switching away from the active app) while one continues using the app they are currently using, as an optional alternative to this historical behavior? Is this supported in any version of Android?

While I appreciate audio calls are a special form of event and notification, phone calls are so 2000! :-)

Comment: So to be clear, you want to avoid the phone app from normally taking over the screen and the user hit the multitask button to switch back to whatever that person was working on before the call?

Comment: Yes. To avoid the phone app taking over the screen, or at least not taking over the screen very entirely in a way making it as cumbersome to keep using the previously active app.